# How to parse a string into date components using pure SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have column of dates that have missing date components, example:

```
publish_date
"1997"
"1997"
"1998"
"1996"
(NULL)
"2006"
"March, 2004"
"February 28, 2007"
"February 28, 2007"
"1997"
```

I would like to take each date and break the components up into 3 (day, month, year) and update the values into 3 new fields for that row.

I thought I can make use of `STR_TO_DATE` but it doesn't work for all incomplete dates.

I can simply do this with PHP but I was hoping for a pure SQL solution, possible?

Comment: What is the data type of `publish_date` ?

Comment: It is varchar, and the quotes around the dates is because the data was in JSON format originally. A bit of a mess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL, you would use the `day()`, `month()`, and `year()` functions.  These should work on partial dates.  If the data is being stored as a string, then you have other problems.

Comment: Yes, I have those problems! In PHP, I would do something like `date('Y', strtotime('1999'))` and I would get `1999`. Anything like this for MySQL?

Comment: @Abs . . . MySQL does allow incomplete dates and these functions work on them (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html).  I thought your question was referring to these.